# Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to follow this tutorial
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee943166.aspx
, but

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;
```

fails for me. I get an error in VS 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5

**The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Would be happy if someone tells how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was solved by downloading and installing **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SDK** and adding **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll** as ProgramFOX proposed.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll`

Comment: Thank, however, it's not in the list of available assemblies. Maybe, I need to install something?

Comment: @user1264304: Go to "Add reference" -> "Assemblies" -> "Extensions" and there you'll find "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0"